# How to store private IP address on Dropbox or Google Drive?

Tags: unix, google-drive-api, ip-address

I am trying to store my private IP Address on my Dropbox or Google Drive account but I have only found guides on how to store the public IP Address and only for Unix OS.

Any idea on how to do that on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Found it on my own:
1) I created a .txt file containing: ipconfig > C:\Users(you own user)\Dropbox\IP_Address.txt (or have it point to wherever you have the dropbox/google drive folder)

2) Saved the .txt file as .bat

3) Went to Windows Task Scheduler and created a Task to run every hour

Now, once every hour, the IP_Address.txt file on my Dropbox account is updated and I can access my computer even if somehow the IP address changes and I can't remote to it from inside the LAN or through a VPN.